# MySQL Count paid sales and orders

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the thing:
I have this `Payment_types`, `Sales`, `Payments` and `Orders` tables, either a sale as an order generate a payment

My tables is thus:

```
Payment_types: id, name (may be a order or a sale)

Payments: id, payment_type_id, sale_id, order_id, price, paid, description

Sales: id, price

Orders: id, price
```

then, if the payment is a sale, the `order_id` is null and vice versa.

then how I will do select to display each table record sales or orders which have their price equal to the sum of the table payments related to that id? and would also like to know if my database is structured correctly.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your expect outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
select Sales.id,
    Max(Sales.price) Sales_price,
    Sum(Payment.price) Payment_price
from Sales, Payment
where Sales.id = Payment.sale_id
group by Sales.id
having Max(Sales.price) = Sum(Payment.price)
```

Your query does not work as expected because you use a WHERE clause on the result of an aggregation, but you should use a HAVING-clause.

Comment: You're welcome :) Regarding your question on the design, could you give more details about what you are trying to do? Especially why to you need/want separate Orders and Sales?

Comment: Because a Payment comes from a Order or a Sale, you know? and then I have this query that filters all the payments that came from Orders and is paid..

Comment: Given that there are no differences between the Order and Sales tables, I would have simply created a "Billing" table with a Sales/Order flag. This way you only have a billing_id in the payment table, making the whole reporting process more simple.

Comment: There are differences, I posted that just to simplify the understanding, or should I really create this Billing table that has the Type (sale or order) and the sale_id and order_id columns?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT Sales.*
  FROM Sales
 WHERE Sales.price = (
                       SELECT SUM(Payments.price)
                         FROM Payments
                        WHERE Payments.sale_id = Sales.id
                     )
```

Comment: Thanks, I got your idea, but I used join :D

Comment: this is mine: `SELECT sum(p.price) AS paid_price, o.id, o.price, CASE WHEN sum(p.price) >= o.price THEN 'YES' else 'NO' END AS paid FROM order o LEFT JOIN payments p ON (p.order_id = o.id) GROUP BY o.id` but I used the @ymog code.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below once.

```
Select * 
from Payments p,sales s,ordes o
where (p.sale_id = s.id and p.price= s.price)
or (p.sale_id = o.id and p.price= o.price)
Order by p.id
```